# golang format leading zeros with sign

Tags: go, formatting

I'd like to format an integer to an UTC offset formatted string

I tried it using the fmt package:

```
fmt.Sprintf("%+02d:00", utc)
```

When utc is 1, I'd like it to print "+01:00", but I get "+1:00"
How can I combine the leading zeros flag, the sign flag and the width in one format string?

Comment: You need to increase the width from two to three https://play.golang.org/p/wHmuRYJng4.

Comment: Thanks! Post it as answer and I will accept it :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> width is the minimum number of runes to output

`+01` is minimum width `3`. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    utc := 1
    s := fmt.Sprintf("%+03d:00", utc)
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/Z0vBzzn-kp

Output:

```
+01:00
```